# Can we connect an Azure mobile service to an on premise web service?

Tags: web-services, azure-mobile-services, azure-vpn

Does anyone know whether it is possible to route network traffic from an azure mobile service through a VPN to an on premise web service? None of the documentation I have read precludes that, but neither does it say we can. So far we have had no success though we can access the web service using a web browser VM in the same subscription. We can't run any new software at the site hosting the web service, so it would seem like Service Bus Relay cant be used and the web service can't have a publicly exposed ip address.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at [Mobile Services with an Azure Hybrid Connection](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-hybrid-connections-get-started/). The walkthrough talks about exposing an on-premise database, but i think you can use the same steps to expose a different TCP port for your on-premise web service